# Castor Integers with empty tags become Zero. Any way to stop that?

Tags: castor

Any way to stop Castor from converting empty tags to Zero?

```
<AMID></AMID>
```

This becomes a Zero Integer but I really want it to blow out or become a -1 so I can pick it up later.

I tried a handler but it seems to be already an Integer when it comes in...

Comment: I know nothing about Castor, but are you binding to an `int` or `Integer` object?  If an int, perhaps it's catching the autoboxing issue and just assigning zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
public void setAmid(String amid) {
...
}
```

setter, and cast the number manually to an integer. You also need to define a set-method attribute in the mapping file like this:

```
<field name="amid" type="string" set-method="setAmid" ...>
```

This is to avoid Castor's confusion when unmarshalling the object.

Comment: Took me a bit to get back to this, but this doesn't work either.  I believe it actually does set it correctly, but then I get a "field 'amid' (whose xml name is 'AMID') is a required field of class 'xxx.xxx.Aftermarkets."  Apparently the "required" setting is messing something up.  And we need it required...

Comment: Well, all I can add, is that the above solution works for me.

The required attribute matters if you use Castor's validation feature. If you have the property defined in the mapping, then if the property/value is defined in the XML document, it's going to be set on the Java object. Without Castor's validation, you can still enforce it on the XML level with a schema.